# Apps name can be found only when searched with two combined keywords

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an app using Android Studio called Sahabat Diabetes and already published it in play store. When I search by typing Sahabat or Diabetes or Sahabat Diabetes, it won't appear. But when I searched using sahabatdiabetes (two words combine as one), it's magically appeared.

The question is: Why? I couldn't think of any possibilities. Is there any settings for keywords in android studio? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have a package name **com.main.sahabatdiabetes**. There are not much things you can do from Android Studio to provide keywords AFAIK. Its all based on your app ranking in the Play Store.

But yes, You can follow all the standards as per the Google Playstore as described in the below link.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en